# Can you mark-word backwards?

Tags: text-editing, mark

There is a very convenient function <kbd>M-@</kbd> Mark-word.

However, I usually find my self typing things, than marking things backwards to copy it some place else.

Is there something equivalent for mark-word-backwards or would I have to write a script to manually mark and go backwards? If so, is there a recommended key sequence to map this to?

Thank you.

Comment: You could use a negative prefix argument: `M-- M-@`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a negative prefix argument to mark backwards, for example:

<kbd>M--</kbd> <kbd>M-@</kbd>

Note that you can also mark a number of words forwards or backwards. For example, mark backwards four words:

<kbd>M--</kbd> <kbd>M-4</kbd> <kbd>M-@</kbd>

Note that by default Emacs binds the prefix keys with a variety of modifiers. This makes it easier to specify a prefix when you are holding down some combination of modifiers for whatever command you are about to call. For example, I often use the following to mark a sexp backwards:

<kbd>C-M--</kbd><kbd>C-M-SPC</kbd>.

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for.

Comment: How do I do this programatically?

Comment: Programatically you can pass an arugment to the `mark-words` function -- that is what happens with the prefix arg keys. So `(mark-word -1)` will mark backwards one word.

Comment: `M--` & 'C--`, does both set the same prefix arg?

Comment: Right. By default M-, C-, and C-M- are all configured to work as modifiers for a prefix argument (a digit or `-`). Of course many people (myself included) end up redefining some of those keys to do other things, but in a stock Emacs setup they are interchangeable.